# VueJS: use data value in style

Tags: css, vue.js, styles

How can I use `data()` values in `<style>..</style>`? I tried several combinations (with/without `this`, with/without `{{brackets}}` etc. but can't get it to work. If I enter a value like `'#f00'` instead it works fine.

I built a template like so:

```
<template>
 <ul class="striped">
     <li>foo</li>
     <li>bar</li>
     <li>foobar</li>
</ul>


</template>

<style>
 ul.striped> li:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: this.colors[0].backgroundcolor;  //dynamic value from data()
}
</style>

<script>

  data() {
    return {

        colors: [{'backgroundcolor':'#def'}], //simplified version for explanation
[..]
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [Vue 3.2 release](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html) you can just use [State-Driven Dynamic CSS](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css) like that :

```html
<template>
    <ul class="striped">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foobar</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<style>
    ul.striped> li:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: v-bind('colors[0]')
    }
</style>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            colors: ['#def'],
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you're using Vue 2 you may use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) like that :

```html
<template>
    <ul class="striped" :style="`--color: ${colors[0]}`">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foobar</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<style>
    ul.striped> li:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: var(--color)
    }
</style>

<script>
   export default {
      data() {
        return {
            colors: ['#def'],
        }
    }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you for both versions, works like a charm.